# How to combine Python dataframe's info output with unique count list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, unique

I read a CSV into dataframe like this and ran `info()`:

```
dlqcsv = pd.read_csv(a1, sep=',', encoding ="ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False, index_col=False)
dd = dlqcsv.info(verbose=True)
dd.describe()
```

It produces:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 504334 entries, 0 to 504333
Data columns (total 288 columns):
Unnamed: 0                 int64
rowno__loan               float64
..... the rest of the 288 features
```

Then I ran the following to count the unique (stealing somebody's code from this website)

```
col_uni_val={}
for i in dlqcsv.columns:
    col_uni_val[i] = len(dlqcsv[i].unique())
import pprint
col_uni_val
```

and got this, which is great

```
{'Unnamed: 0': 504334,
 'rowno_loan': 55851,
.. the rest of the 288 pairs..
```

I want to combine the verbose `info` output with the `unique count` output. Obviously, this is a simple one-to-one unique inner-join with no repeats in the matching key.

How to call up the columns of the feature names in both tables? Neither seems to have column names?

Also, possible to write out the count to a data frame directly instead of a dictionary? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a inbuilt method for counting unique values. You can get your output using `dlqcsv.nunique()`

For the overall task that you are asking for, manipulating `df.info` is a much harder task. An easier option would be to use something like the below code that calculates all required values for your columns.

```
output = []

for col in df.columns:

    nonNull  = len(df) - np.sum(pd.isna(df[col]))
    unique = df[col].nunique()
    colType = str(df[col].dtype)

    output.append([col, nonNull, unique, colType])

output = pd.DataFrame(output)   
output.columns = ['colName','non-null values', 'unique', 'dtype']
```

The output looks like:

```
     colName  non-null values  unique    dtype
0      le_id               20       5    int64
1    run_seq               20       5    int64
2      cp_id               20       8    int64
3    cp_name               20       8   object
4   products               20       7   object
5  tran_amnt               20      17    int64
6   currency               20       6   object
7    current                1       1  float6
```

Comment: Thank you, Roshan. It worked. Agree df.info() is for viewing mainly not for manipulation. Wonder (nothing against anybody) if we could morph df.info() to be more useful. If not turning on verbose, little meaning to look at it. Turning on verbose does not add value either because it is not manipulation friendly. Side note: nunique does run much faster when the frame fits in memory on Linux, beating SAS data step. When # of columns is, in my testing, >40000, ill-fitting memory? it still beats SAS DS, but trails SAS DS2  in counting unique. It does not appear swapping disk space as efficiently.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. If you want to see the null values count on your table, then add the following variable: nullValues = np.sum(pd.isna(df_train[col])) and don't forget to add it into the output.append and into the output.columns lines for it to show.